# Why does jQuery return null for element height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I faced the same problem as that is mentioned by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680811/jquery-returns-null-for-element-height-why) but it is little different. I am trying to get height of a div but every time I get `null`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main" class="box-main " style="display:block">
    <div class="box_content" style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;height:453px;width:100%;padding-left:5px;padding-bottom:2px;">
        <div style="min-width:200px;min-height:41px;padding-top:8px" id="ass-1415241823647 item-97"><div class="box">
           <div class="new-try item_message" title="ram"><div class="pp"><img src="images/try.jpg" class="avatar " width="40" height="40"></div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($("#ass-1415241823647 .item_message").height());
});
```

I tried this too but it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($("#main .box_content #ass-1415241823647 .box .item_message").height());
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ass-1415241823647 item-97`   you can't have two id's remove one or try using class if u really want to

Comment: yes it will dear but if you really want to name for ids then use classes because id can only be one per element but classes can be many ! @BibashAdhikari

Comment: You can follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884862/why-use-ids-classs-in-html-why-not-just-one

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have any elements in your markup matching the selector `#ass-1415241823647 .item_message"` so it's unable to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the result of $("#ass-1415241823647 .item_message") empty jQueryObject? length 0?

```
.. id="ass-1415241823647 item-97">..
```

value of id attributes was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($(".item_message").css("height"));
});
```

Hope this helps.